# OSError: cannot identify image file 'dataSet/.DS_Store'

Tags: opencv, python-imaging-library

I am trying to run a facial recognition trainer that looks at a folder of jpg images of faces

```
import os                                               # importing the OS for path
import cv2                                              # importing the OpenCV library
import numpy as np                                      # importing Numpy library
from PIL import Image                                   # importing Image library

EigenFace = cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create(15)      # creating EIGEN FACE RECOGNISER
FisherFace = cv2.face.FisherFaceRecognizer_create(2)     # Create FISHER FACE RECOGNISER
LBPHFace = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create(1, 1, 7,7) # Create LBPH FACE RECOGNISER

path = 'dataSet'                                        # path to the photos
def getImageWithID (path):
    imagePaths = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
    FaceList = []
    IDs = []
    for imagePath in imagePaths:
        faceImage = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L')  # Open image and convert to gray
        faceImage = faceImage.resize((110,110))         # resize the image so the EIGEN recogniser can be trained
        faceNP = np.array(faceImage, 'uint8')           # convert the image to Numpy array
        ID = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')[1])    # Retrieve the ID of the array
        FaceList.append(faceNP)                         # Append the Numpy Array to the list
        IDs.append(ID)                                  # Append the ID to the IDs list
        cv2.imshow('Training Set', faceNP)              # Show the images in the list
        cv2.waitKey(1)
    return np.array(IDs), FaceList                      # The IDs are converted in to a Numpy array
IDs, FaceList = getImageWithID(path)
```

which in turn returns the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jef/PycharmProjects/testProject/Python/Trainer_All.py", line 28, in <module>
    IDs, FaceList = getImageWithID(path)
  File "/Users/jef/PycharmProjects/testProject/Python/Trainer_All.py", line 19, in getImageWithID
    faceImage = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L')  # Open image and convert to gray
  File "/Users/jef/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2452, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file 'dataSet/.DS_Store'
```

The folder dataSet exists and i'm running the code on my mac, and the most recent versions of Pillow, numpy and cv2, I've googled the OSError but not much came up to help this particular problem. Any ideas?

Comment: ...it's trying to read `.DS_Store` which isn't an image. Delete it from your folder. Or just in `imagePaths` remove `.DS_Store`. Better yet just use `glob` and only grab files that end with `.jpg` or `.png` or whatever extension your images use.

Comment: I checked the folder and didnt see anything like '.DS_Store' only a few .jpg images. Would you mind telling me how to change my code to implement glob?

Comment: macOS inserts a `.DS_Store` file in folders that you visit as a way to help the OS load things faster. It holds the preferences for icons and such inside the folder. Files that start with a `.` are hidden files that you cannot see normally inside a Finder window. Navigate to the folder in terminal and you'll see it in a `ls -a`. You can delete it with `rm .DS_Store` inside terminal but macOS may put it there again the next time you view the folder in Finder.

Comment: `import glob` at the top of your file and `imagePaths = [f for f in glob.glob('directory/*.png')]`. This will grab all files inside `directory` that end with `.png`. Of course switch it out for other extensions as needed.

Comment: Kinda curious -- you already `import cv2`, so why do you need PIL to load the image?

Answer (score 7):

`os.listdir()` will give you every single file in the directory, including hidden files like `.DS_Store`. In macOS, `.DS_Store` is a hidden file (any file starting with a `.` is hidden from Finder) inserted in directories whenever you view them with Finder to speed up loading the file icons and saving your preferences for thumbnail sizes and such in that folder. You can read more about the file [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store).

You can see the file if you navigate to the directory and list the files in terminal with `ls -a`.

In any case, you just need to not try and read that as an image file. There are a bazillion ways to avoid this, here's a few:

```
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    if imagePath == directory + '.DS_Store':
        continue
    # rest of your program
```

or

```
imagePaths = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
if directory + '.DS_Store' in imagePaths:
    imagePaths.remove(directory + '.DS_Store')
```

or just use `glob` to grab files only with the extensions you want:

```
import glob
imagePaths = [f for f in glob.glob(directory+'*.jpg')]  # or .png, .tif, etc
```

Here the `*` is a wildcard meaning "any sequence of characters" so this will grab `directory/1.jpg` and `directory/asdf.jpg` and all other possibilities starting with `directory/` and ending with `.jpg`.

Or just remove it from your directory in terminal with

```
rm .DS_Store
```

but this is only a temporary solution as macOS will insert the file again next time you view the folder in Finder.

Answer (score 1):

On terminal, cd directory and run rm .DS_Store