# Keras - OSError: cannot identify image file

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a CNN with Keras and when running the `model.fit_generator` line of code, I get the following error:

```
OSError: cannot identify image file      
'D:\\PDF\\Train\\notfactors\\notfactors59.jpg
```

The wierd thing is, that `.jpg` does not exist in the folder.  Below is all of my code.

I'm using the exact same code (different data) from the following github address:

https://github.com/deeplizard/Keras_Jupyter_Notebooks/blob/master/CNN.ipynb

This problem was dicussed here:
[OSError: cannot identify image file 'dataSet/.DS_Store'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645115/oserror-cannot-identify-image-file-dataset-ds-store)

But for this question, the images actually exists.  I'm lost.  Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about the exact cause but it seems some of the data is corrupt or damaged this might happen while changing the extension on image eg: png to jpg. I was facing the same error and resolved it deleting those images (had to delete 12/1802 images).

Answer (score 1):

The `model.fit_generator` function call looks like this in the jupyter notebook:

```
model.fit_generator(train_batches, steps_per_epoch=4, 
                    validation_data=valid_batches, validation_steps=4, epochs=5, verbose=2)
```

You are passing the `train_batches` variable as a parameter. What does that look like?

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['dog', 'cat'], batch_size=10)
```

That assignment is looking in the `train_path` location for images.

`train_path = 'cats-and-dogs/train'` which is a relative path. Your error message says that it cannot find an image at the location `'D:\\PDF\\Train\\notfactors\\notfactors59.jpg` which is not defined anywhere in the notebook provided in the link.

Can you update your question and provide the values for the calls from the notebook you are using? It does not appear you are using the exact code in the notebook. That will help troubleshoot this further.

Comment: My apologies @Nathan for the confusion.  I can't post my data so I posted the script with data that can be used.  Now that I'm back in the office, I found that if I copied the pictures, and posted them to a new folder, I no longer get the error.  That doesn't answer the "why" but at least the CNN is running now.

Comment: Sounds like it was a file permission problem. If you 'copied' the files and they worked, could be that the CNN code was unable to read the original files. Or there was a file path issue.